# PHP: Show the difference in two arrays when elements out of order

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to test if two arrays contain the same elements and in the same order. For example:

```
$a = ['id', 'name', 'age', 'gender'];
$b = ['id', 'age', 'name', 'gender'];
```

How can I extract just the part that doesn't match up:

```
Expected: name, age
Found: age, name
```

Comment: What code did you used for this?

Comment: [array_diff_assoc()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff-assoc.php) - [Demo](http://3v4l.org/AOQ0e)

Comment: I haven't started it, or I would have posted the code ;) array_diff_assoc seemed to work perfectly, thanks Mark.

Comment: array_diff_assoc() =Computes the difference of arrays with additional **index check**

Comment: Mark if you add answer I will accept. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [array_diff_assoc()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff-assoc.php) to do this, it works out the difference between the two arrays, with a key check to verify that the keys are the same as well:

```
$a = ['id', 'name', 'age', 'gender'];
$b = ['id', 'age', 'name', 'gender'];

$expected = array_diff_assoc($a, $b);
$actual = array_diff_assoc($b, $a);

echo 'Expected = ', implode(', ', $expected), PHP_EOL;
echo 'Actual = ', implode(', ', $actual), PHP_EOL;
```

[Demo](http://3v4l.org/0uLR3)

Comment: Perfect, thanks. I had a feeling there might be an existing php function I could use I just couldn't find it :)

Answer (score 0):

to find out which elements are not contained in another array use array_diff().

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php

but this won't solve your problem. You could manually do like:

```
$temp = array();
if (count($array1) == count($array2) {
  for($i = 0; $i < count($array1); $i++){
    if ($array1[$i] != $array2[$i]) $temp[] = array("expected" => $array1[$i], "found" => $array2[$i];
  }
}
return $temp;
```

`$temp` will contain the diffs in the form `array("expected" => first value, "found" => second_value);`

Answer (score 0):

this could work for you

```
<?php

$a = ['id', 'name', 'age', 'gender'];
$b = ['id', 'age', 'name', 'gender'];

$error_a = array();
$error_b = array();


for ($i=0; $i < sizeof($a); $i++) { 
  if($a[$i]==$b[$i]){
    //no error
  }else{
    array_push($error_a, $a[$i]);
    array_push($error_b, $b[$i]);
  }
 }

var_dump($error_a);
var_dump($error_b);

?>
```